# R split,sort,unique,paste in data table

Tags: r, split, data.table, unique

I have a data table as below. I would like to split on '/', sort the resulting list, take unique values, and then paste it by collapsing on '/' in R. I would like to achieve this in data.table or stringr packages. Is it possible?

input>>

```
> dt<-data.table(id=c('id1','id2','id3','id4','id5'),value=c('a/b/a/b','b/a/c/a/b','c/d/c/a','a/b/b','a/a/c/b'))
> dt
    id     value
1: id1   a/b/a/b
2: id2 b/a/c/a/b
3: id3   c/d/c/a
4: id4     a/b/b
5: id5   a/a/c/b
```

expected output>>

```
> dt
    id     value
1: id1       a/b
2: id2     a/b/c
3: id3     a/c/d
4: id4       a/b
5: id5     a/b/c
```

I tried the following but it did not work.

```
> dt<-dt[,value1:=paste(sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(value, "/")))),collapse='/')]
> dt
    id     value  value1
1: id1   a/b/a/b a/b/c/d
2: id2 b/a/c/a/b a/b/c/d
3: id3   c/d/c/a a/b/c/d
4: id4     a/b/b a/b/c/d
5: id5   a/a/c/b a/b/c/d
```

I also tried using list and gave the right result, but this can get cumbersome if the number of other variables in data table are large.

```
> dt<-dt[,list(value1=paste(sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(value,"/")))),collapse='/')),by=c('id','value')]
> dt
    id     value value1
1: id1   a/b/a/b    a/b
2: id2 b/a/c/a/b  a/b/c
3: id3   c/d/c/a  a/c/d
4: id4     a/b/b    a/b
5: id5   a/a/c/b  a/b/c
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Please note the [conventions for formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to split the 'value' by `/`, grouped by 'id', get the `sort`ed `unique` values and `paste` it together

```
dt[, .(value = paste(sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(value, "/")))), collapse="/")), id]
#    id value
#1: id1   a/b
#2: id2 a/b/c
#3: id3 a/c/d
#4: id4   a/b
#5: id5 a/b/c
```

---

if there are many columns, then we can update the 'value' by looping through the `split` elements and doing the `sort/unique/paste` within each `list`

```
dt[, value := unlist(lapply(strsplit(value, "/"), 
        function(x) paste(sort(unique(x)), collapse="/")))]
```

Comment: This works correctly, but is there a simpler way without having to mention "id" as a by variable? In the actual dataset, I have a lot of fields and having to mention all of them as a by variable is cumbersome.

Comment: Can you edit you question with an example of what you mean? As in, you want to collapse other variables for `id`, or other grouping variables apply to `value` as well?

Comment: @Amit  Sorry, I missed this message.  Updated the post